# DataGridViewComboBox value is not valid linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

Im filling my datagridview comboxcolumn with this code:

```
 (dgvHopDong.Columns["MaNCC"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = QL.NhaCungCaps.Select(n => new { MaNCC = n.MaNCC, TenNCC = n.TenNCC }).ToList();            
            (dgvHopDong.Columns["MaNCC"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = "TenNCC";
            (dgvHopDong.Columns["MaNCC"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "MaNCC";
```

and the error is:

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid?

and i dont know why.
thank you so much!

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The value type is missing.

```
(dgvHopDong.Columns["MaNCC"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueType = typeof(string);
```